# Clean all NetBeans references

Tags: java, netbeans-7

For no reason my NetBeans 7.1.2 on Windows XP stop showing my web applications projects. So, everytime I run my IDE I have to clean the projects folder and create a new web project.

I tried:

- Reinstall the IDE;
- Remove .netbeans folder under my user home folder;
- Reinstall plugins inside the IDE;

I have no more ideas except formatting my entire machine. Is there anyway to clean all NetBeans references and including windows registry?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking that projects are stored in their own folders so, if Netbeans is not showing projects that were open in the last session you'd just have to open them, not creating them. So, I don't think I understood your problem.

Comment: The problem is that even with my Web Applications opened, they disappear without an error message. It's simply stop showing in my projects tab. I have now 10 projects. 8 are desktop and they are shown, but the 2 web projects do not show even when I try opening them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. There was nothing wrong about NetBeans cache.

I had change the location of one jar and forgot to update a Library containing a reference to this jar.

It's weird because NetBeans shows things like this as Reference Problems. But in this specific case it had hide the projects.

So, I expect that this can help someone.